# character counting game android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, textview

I am building a simple letter counting application, it takes a number input from `editText` and check if that is the correct number of letters in the `textView(random name)`, when the button is clicked and displays correct if the correct number is inputted or else not correct, it keeps displaying not correct each time.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText EditTextInput;
    String strInput;
    Button btn;
    TextView txtLenght;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         EditTextInput= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        EditTextInput.getText().toString();

        txtLenght = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txtLenght.getText().toString();

       btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {






                if (EditTextInput==txtLenght )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Guess is correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Guess is wrong!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };


});
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will be like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText EditTextInput;
    String strInput;
    Button btn;
    TextView txtLenght;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        EditTextInput= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        int length = Integer.parseInt(EditTextInput.getText().toString());
        txtLenght = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(length == txtLenght.getText().toString().length()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Guess is correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Guess is wrong!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Avijit Karmakar it work, but i had to parse the Integer inside the onClick class only then it worked, thanks again.